# Returning a Promise from "describe" is not supported. Tests must be defined synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

Particular test passed but I am getting this.

```
    console.log node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:502
          ● 

Test suite failed to run

            Returning a Promise from "describe" is not supported. Tests must be defined synchronously.
            Returning a value from "describe" will fail the test in a future version of Jest.

        > 4 | describe('handlers.getSemesters', async () => {
```

Here is complete test code

```
describe('handlers.getSemesters', async () => {
      it('should return an array of Semesters', async () => {
        academicCalendarRequest.request = jest.fn();
        academicCalendarRequest.request.mockReturnValue([
          {
            description: 'Semester1',
          }
        ]);
        const expected = [      
          {
            description: 'Semester1',
          },
        ];

        const handlers = new Handlers();
        const actual = await handlers.getSemesters();
        expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
      });
    });
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Change

```
describe('handlers.getSemesters', async () => {
```

To

```
describe('handlers.getSemesters', () => {
```

And then put asynchronous code inside of `it` block

```
it('should return an array of Semesters', async () => {
  // ...
})
```

Comment: En explanation why he should do so would have been great.

Comment: The docs give a bit more information about defining async tests: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting#defining-tests

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to get async result for working within multiple tests. "Describe" has to be sync and we can't use nested test blocks:

```
describe('Not valid nested structure', () => {
    it('async parent', async () => {
        it('child', () => {})
    });
});
```

So my solution is:

```
    describe('TaskService', () => {
        let testTask;
        
        // Common async test
        it('should set test task', async () => {
            testTask = await connection.create();
            // you can add expect here
        });

        it('should update task', async () => {
            testTask.status = null;
            const updated = await connection.update(testTask);

            expect(updated.status).toEqual(null);
        });

        it('other operation with testTask above', async () => {
            // ..
        });
    });
```

Comment: I have a similar situation, except my first async task is to call the db for data.  Then second `it` is the test each row of data with `it.each` (instead of your 2nd `it(...)`.  So my equivalent of `testTask` is `dbResults`.  However `dbResults` are undefined because it doesn't seem to evaluate the first `it` before the 2nd.