# Defining dynamic Array in Typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, protractor, integration-testing, undefined

I have a requirement where i want to read a particular value x(that is auto-generated everytime) in a loop of say n times. Now, i want to store these autogenerated values of x, so, that i can later use them and iterate over it to perform my tests(protractor).

The way, i am trying to do is by creating an Array, using `let list: string[] = [];`. Now, i am pushing the values to my defined list using, `list.push[x];` in each iteration. By the end of loop expecting to get the resulting Array having n values of x(string) in my `list` array. In order to validate, i did `console.log(list);` in each iteration and i can see that these values are being pushed in the defined `list`.

Later, in my code if i am trying to access these elements using `let item = list[0];` i am getting the `undefined` value.

I think i need to initialize the Array to some particular size having default values initially and then modify them later in the loop. But, being new to TypeScript i am not able to find a solution on how to do it. Please help, TIA!!

Here, is the snippet below :

```
    const tests = [
{type: 'admin', id='', uname='foo', pass='bar'},
{type: 'super', id='', uname='foo1', pass='bar'},
{type: 'normal', id='customId', uname='foo', pass='bar'}
];

let list: string[] = [];
// let list = [         //this is the final list that i got from the console.log(list);
// 'QR417msytVrq',
// 'V0fxayA3FOBD',
// 'QnaiegiVoYhs'];

describe(`Open Page `, () => {
  //Code to get to the page

  beforeAll(async () => {
    //initialize page objects

  });

  describe(`Login User `, async () => {
    tests.forEach(test => {
      it(` should login user with `+test.type, async () => {

        //....
        //....


        // On Success
        const myId = userPage.getUID().getText();

        list.push(myId);
        console.log(list);
        console.log(list.length);
      });
    });
  });


  describe(`Delete User`, async () => {

    // describe(`Confirmation `, async () => {
    console.log(list);
    // list.forEach(item => {       //this code doesn't gets executed and wasn't giving any error, so, commented out and tried to access the first element which is undefined.
      let item = list[0];
      console.log(item);            //getting undefined value here. 
      it(` should select and Delete the User having id as ` + item, async () => {
        //code to remove the user having id as item.
      });
    // });
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is because you are using the push function not correctly.
From your example, you are using `list.push[x]`, However, you might be looking for `iten.push(x)`. The latter will add an element do the array. Either that or there is something else in your code that is reseting the array. It might help if you posted the relevent part of your code.

Comment: Added the snippet of what i am trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Options to test deleting a user:

Ultimately, it's [bad practice to make tests dependent on other tests](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274655/how-to-make-one-test-depend-on-the-results-of-another-test).

That said, two or possibly three options which should work:

#### A: Iterate through list of users within one test

```js
describe(`Delete User`, async () => {
    describe(`Confirmation `, () => {
        it(`Log all users out who previously logged in`, async () => {
            list.forEach((item) => {
                console.log(item);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Since the `list` array is populated by the previous test, inserting the code dependent on it inside of the next test would ensure that it has values to work with.

#### B: Login and delete user in one test

```js
describe(`Login and delete user `, async () => {
    tests.forEach(test => {
        it(` should login and delete user with ` + test.type, async () => {
            const myId = userPage.getUID().getText();
            // Select and delete myId here
        });
    });
});
```

You may be able to remove the `list` array entirely by putting the entirety of the user flow into one large integration test.

#### C: Use mock data (may not be applicable if data is random)

```js
describe(`Delete User`, async () => {
    const list = ["QR417msytVrq", "V0fxayA3FOBD", "QnaiegiVoYhs"];
    describe(`Confirmation `, () => {
        list.forEach((item) => {
            it(
                ` should select and Delete the User having id as ` + item,
                async () => {}
            );
        });
    });
});
```

If you know what the values to delete are going to be ahead of time, you can add them in manually. If the values are randomly generated, this won't work.

### Other problems:

#### Testing order of execution

The dynamic array syntax you're using looks right however you appear to have an order of execution problem in your tests.

The code in the `describe` functions that is outside of the specs (the `it` blocks) is executed before any of the code inside of the specs is. The testing framework will traverse the tree of `describe` blocks, executing any code it finds but only taking note of the `it` specs. When it's finished this, it then executes the `it` specs it found in sequential order.

When you attempt to save the value of `list[0]`, the `'Login User'` specs have yet to be executed. More specifically:

```js
describe(`Login User `, async () => {
    tests.forEach(test => {
        it(` should login user with ` + test.type, async () => {
            // This code is executed AFTER the code in the 'Delete User' 
            // block but BEFORE the 'Delete User' spec
            const myId = userPage.getUID().getText();
            list.push(myId);
        });
    });
});


describe(`Delete User`, async () => {
    // This code is executed before any specs are run
    let item = list[0];
    // List is [] when item is initialized
    // The following spec will therefore not work as item is undefined
    it(` should select and Delete the User having id as ` + item, async () => {
    });
});
```

A possible solution to this would be to change the string of the `'Delete User'` spec to something like `' should select and Delete first User'` as well as move all the code outside of the spec to inside.

#### Describe blocks should not return promises

Your code sample has `describe` blocks (specifically `'Login User'`, `'Delete User'`, and `'Confirmation'`) which return Promises. You should remove the `async` in front of the function declarations. The specs can and should remain the same. For example:

```js
describe(`Login User `, () => {
```

#### Object syntax

The tests object at the start of your sample isn't using JS/TS object syntax. Each key should be followed by a colon before the value instead of an equals sign. You likely meant to write:

```js
const tests = [{
        type: 'admin',
        id: '',
        uname: 'foo',
        pass: 'bar'
    },
    {
        type: 'super',
        id: '',
        uname: 'foo1',
        pass: 'bar'
    },
    {
        type: 'normal',
        id: 'customId',
        uname: 'foo',
        pass: 'bar'
    }
];
```

Sources:

- [Jest docs describing order of execution](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown#order-of-execution-of-describe-and-test-blocks)
- [SO on Promise returning in `describe` blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56640062/returning-a-promise-from-describe-is-not-supported-tests-must-be-defined-sync)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but what should be done if i have to iterate over the `list` and perform delete operation on each list item. In that case i have to define use `list.forEach` in describe block like mentioned below, in this case its not even executing, any other alternative to perform this? :

`{
describe(`Delete User`, () => {

    list.forEach(item => {        
      it(` should select and remove User having id as ` + item, async () => {
        //code to remove the user having id as item.
      });
    });
 });
}`

Comment: And, yes for `tests` i have typed them here without paying much attention on syntax. These are defined correctly in my code though, still thinking what can be done if i have to iterate over `list` and call my same spec on each item in the list.

Comment: Updated answer to add in some possible solutions to the dependent test problem.